# Google Sheets Count number of occurances during each hour of every day

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to get a count on the number of times that the word "HEATING" shows up for each hour of each day.

I tried multiple options with unique, countif, countifs, left (trying to get the first 13 characters of each cell containing the timestamp).

Sample spreadsheet is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oZMmiFK34PQKVB0z4gK8XKodG-CqPM9HYp1eB5trFo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula:

```
=QUERY(
  A:D,
  "SELECT DAY(A), HOUR(A), COUNT(D) WHERE D = 'HEATING' GROUP BY DAY(A), HOUR(A)"
)
```

I assumed that you also need the day.  You can add month/year the same way.

[image: Sample result]

Comment: That's perfect...almost!!  You rock!  Since this is for the entire year, I wanted to add Month, along with your Day and Hour.  I modified it to this:  

=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT MONTH(A), DAY(A), HOUR(A), COUNT(D) WHERE D = 'HEATING' GROUP BY MONTH(A), DAY(A), HOUR(A)")

However, it's showing the month as ) for every entry.  What did I do wrong there?

Thanks again, dataful.tech!!

Comment: I assume you mean that all month are 0's.  It happens because `QUERY` counts months from 0, so January is 0.  To make it more human readable, you can add 1 to the months column: `=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT MONTH(A) + 1, DAY(A), HOUR(A), COUNT(D) WHERE D = 'HEATING' GROUP BY MONTH(A), DAY(A), HOUR(A)")`.

Comment: @JoeS If it solved your problem, could you please accept it so your question is marked as answered.

Comment: OK, I overlooked something.  I need the output slightly different.  I want it to show everything as it is, but in the next column over, I would like it to show the number of occurrences that the same cell (D) shows OFF.

So, first column shows Month, second column shows Day, next column shows Hour, next column shows the number of times that hour has HEATING, and the column that I need to be added would be one to show the number of times that the hour shows OFF.

Comment: @JoeS should the table include only the time periods that had HEATING, OFF, both, or any period that had any data?

Comment: I want it to show 0 when there aren't any occurances of 'HEATING' for that hour?

Comment: Then you need to use another approach, for example this one:  the first formula will generate unique sorted month-day-hour values `=sort(unique(map(A2:A, lambda(dt, if(isblank(dt),, {month(dt), day(dt), hour(dt)})))), 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)` and the second will count number of occurrences of HEATING or OFF: `=map(F2:F, G2:G, H2:H, lambda(m, d, h, if(isblank(m),, counta(ifna(filter(D2:D, D2:D="HEATING", hour(A2:A)=h, month(A2:A)=m, day(A2:A)=d))))))` (similar for OFF).  This is a sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ny3mPpfpZgLhH7b9UBkk1ZaYlNptD2s3ZBgoSF-tUuA/edit#gid=0 .

Comment: You are amazing dataful.tech!  Thank you

Comment: LOL!!  @dataful.tech, can I ask one more question relating to this spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure.  I hope moderators wouldn't mind this chatting in the comments )

Comment: Good point!  I created a new question.  Here is the link to it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862229/average-per-hour-per-day