# Average per hour per day

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

This is a follow up from the question in this link:  [Google Sheets Count number of occurances during each hour of every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77842095/google-sheets-count-number-of-occurances-during-each-hour-of-every-day)

I want to take each hour of each day, in column A on the thermostatLogs tab and average out the wind chill during that particular hour, column W on the same tab.

Here is the sample spreadsheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mlT84VPnIofRiQlf4Wiec_2EXqcA4b8fNNlTQ0AOHGg/edit?usp=sharing

On the Charted Hourly tab, I have the table showing the total number of times the word "HEATING" shows up per hour, HUGE thanks to dataful.tech.  What I want to do from here is take the Wind Chill (column W on thermostatLogs) for each hour.  So, for example, the average wind chill (taken from thermostatLogs column W) during the 15:00 hour on 1/18 was 1.1 degrees.

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Sorry, it posted the title of the question but it's within this website.  It's isn't another site.  It just points to my other question within Stackoverflow web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample spreadsheet you provided, you can average column W for each hour with this formula in cell G2: `=map(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, lambda(m, d, h, if(isblank(m),, iferror(AVERAGE(ifna(filter(thermostatLogs!W2:W, hour(thermostatLogs!A2:A)=h, month(thermostatLogs!A2:A)=m, day(thermostatLogs!A2:A)=d)))))))`.

[image: Sample result]

Comment: Once again, dataful.tech!  Thank you so much!